# Do we always need to use UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING while using last_value() function?

Tags: sql, oracle

In SQL, do we always need to use `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` while using `last_value` function in analytical functions?

I saw this example where if we just used:

```
SELECT employee_id, salary, last_value(salary) over(order by salary ASC)
FROM employees;
```

This did not give the expected output which was supposed to give the employee with the highest salary.

Instead they had to use windowing:

```
SELECT employee_id, salary, 
    last_value(salary) over (
        order by salary ASC ROWS BETWEEN CURRENT ROW AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING)
FROM employees;
```

So I was just wondering if while using `last_value` function, do we always need to use `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is basically "yes", because the default window frame is `range between unbounded preceding and current row`.  And the last value would normally be on the current row.

One exception is when you are using `ignore nulls`.  Then `last_value(ignore nulls)` is very useful for getting the most recent row -- including the current row -- with a non-`NULL` value.

By the way, this is the reason that I usually use `first_value()` with a reversed `order by`:

```
first_value(salary) over (order by salary desc)
```

Or for this example, `max()` is simpler:

```
max(salary) over ()
```